# The Change-making problem algorithm proof (at the dynamic programming method)

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, dynamic-programming

I saw here the algorithm for the "Change-making problem" (at the dynamic programming method).
I saw it here: http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F07/dynamic.pdf

I'm trying to find a proof for this algorithm. I try to prove it with induction but I think that it wont work at all...

I'd like if you will help me how to prove it.
If you have source at the internet it will be good to..

Thank you!

Comment: This may be helpful. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/when-can-a-greedy-algorithm-solve-the-coin-change-problem

Comment: When you say "a proof for this algorithm", do you mean a proof that it is _correct_? Dynamic programming algorithms are natural candidates for being proved correct by induction -- possibly long induction.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained as much as possible; you could have described the algorithm. Anyway this is more of a [cs.se] question.

Comment: @JeffreyL. - Yes, but is about the greedy algorithm... I need a proof for the other algo. I'll ask at CS..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a set $D=\{d_1,\ldots,d_m\}\subset\mathbb N$ of coin denominations, for $n\in\mathbb N_0$ let $f(n)$ denote the minimum number of coins (with repetition) in $D$ needed to obtain sum $n$ (or $f(n)=\infty$ if it is ompossible). Then clearly $f(n)\ge 0$ for all $n$ and $f(n)=0\iff n=0$.

If $n>0$ and a way to obtain $n$ with $f(n)$ coins uses at least on coin of denomination $d_k$ (at least one such $k$ exists), then removing this coin we obtain a way to obtain $n-d_k$ and hence conclude $$f(n-d_k)\le f(n)-1\quad \text{for at least one $1\le k\le m$}$$
On the other hand, if $1\le k\le m$ and $n\ge d_k$ we obtain a way to obtain $n$ with $f(n-d_k)+1$ coins by adding a $d_k$ coin to an optimal way to get $n-d_k$. We conclude
$$ f(n)\le f(n-d_k)+1\quad \text{for all $1\le k\le m$ with $n\ge d_k$}.$$
Together this gives us
$$\tag1 f(n)=\min\{\,f(n-d_k)+1\mid 1\le k\le m,n\ge d_k\,\}\quad \text{for all $n>0$}$$
(with the $\min\emptyset=\infty$ understood).
And $(1)$ together with $f(0)=0$ is precisely what the DP algorithm uses to compute $f(n)$ recursively.

Comment: This is proof the whole algorithm, right? Thank you!